# ConEmu how to change default colorscheme for consoles

Tags: conemu

After the most recent update, the ConEmu console color scheme changed to some strange dark blue background with gray text display. Is there an option to have the color scheme reflect the default color scheme for the console? (i.e. Git bash has a green/yellow colorscheme, etc.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually I can't understand why any may dislike eye candy [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color scheme.

[image: git add in ConEmu]

But of course anyone may choose its own favorite color scheme. And ConEmu is shipped with many predefined schemes even "Windows standard".

[image: Predefined color schemes]

Comment: Is it possible to not use any color scheme and just use the system defaults for color and font? I'm using this utility called concfg that configures nice command line colors, but conemu seems to override them.

Comment: Just create new ConEmu palette with same colors as you have set in RealConsole.

Comment: @Maximus To answer your question about liking the theme, for me at least it's not that the theme looks bad (it doesn't I actually prefer it) but when I run scripts with coloured text output all the colours look wonky. Red becomes orange, cyan becomes gray etc, etc.

Comment: For me, the reason was that I often switch between ConEmu and browser, which is most times white bg. After every switch, it takes seconds until my monitor restore it's full brightness.